# Would this electrostatic force written in this form be conservative for some n different from 2?

Tags: electrostatics, energy-conservation

Assume an electrostatic force is given in this form:
$$\vec{F}(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\frac{qQ}{r^{n}}\hat{r}$$
How do I determine whether this new force written in this form for some n is a conservative force?
Can I still use the same concept that 
$$\oint_S f(\vec{r}) \,d\vec{r} = 0\,?$$
This is a random thought: what happens if
$$\vec{F}(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}qQf(r)\hat{r}\,?$$ 
Does it really matter, if f(r) represents a function of distance between the charges, the $F(\vec{r})$ will still be conservative?

Thank you!

Comment: In how many dimensions?

Comment: Would dimensions matter in general?

Comment: Suggestion to v.2: remove the irrelevant factor $\frac{qQ}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$. It adds nothing to the question.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a homework-like question, I would say:

Look at the fundamental theorem of calculus, in vector form.

Do the number of variables in the vector appear in it?

Then think about the consequences of this for line integrals in n dimensions.

Comment: A good way to answer a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to see if $\vec\nabla\times \vec E=0$.  If true, then you are guaranteed by Stokes theorem that
$$ 
\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec \ell =0
$$
for arbitrarily closed circuits and so that 
$\int_a^b \vec E\cdot d\vec \ell=0$ for an arbitrary path from $a\to b$.